# Get relative path of the page url using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, absolute-path

In javascript, how can I get the relative path of the current url?

for example `http://www.example.com/test/this?page=2`

I want just the `/test/this?page=2`

Comment: Why don't you check this thing out:
http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-parse.php half way down the page shows you how to extract different parts using javascript regular expressions.

Comment: That's the relative path

Comment: @BenTaliadoros is right - someone should edit the question and description to correctly say "relative path" instead of "absolute path".

Comment: @jbyrd https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10865424

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.pathname+window.location.search
```

Answer (score 5):

The quickest, most complete way:

```
location.href.replace(/(.+\w\/)(.+)/,"/$2");
```

Comment: Not complete, will match full url if there is no path. Returns `https://stackoverflow.com/` for example.

Answer (score 4):

```
location.href
```

holds the url of the page your script is running in.

Answer (score 4):

`location.href.replace(location.origin,'');`

Only weird case:
`http://foo.com/ >> "/"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below snippet to get the absolute url of any  page.

```
 var getAbsoluteUrl = (function() {
     var a;
     return function(url) {
         if(!a) a = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = url;
         return a.href;
     }
})();
    
// Sample Result based on the input.
getAbsoluteUrl('/'); //Returns http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Checkout [get absolute URL using Javascript](https://itsmycode.com/get-absolute-url-using-javascript/) for more details and multiple ways to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
var absURL = document.URL;
alert(absURL);
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use it the javascript way, to retrieve the complete path including the extensions from the page,

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

So, a path like this, can be retrieved too.

```
www.google.com/results#tab=2
```

Comment: That's the jQuery way. Why not `location.href' as given in an earlier answer?