# Get Absolute Uri in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i do the same in clean JavaScript

```
var url = '<%=Request.Url.AbsoluteUri%>';
```

Thats all!

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged `asp.net` if you don't want it to use `asp.net`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504686/get-absolute-path-of-the-page-url-using-javascript

Comment: @crush — I'm assuming that AbsoluteUri in ASP.NET contains an absolute URI, not just an absolute path, so this isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @crush - You need knowledge of ASP.NET to be able to answer this question. Please do not downvote questions that are properly covered.

Comment: Now two downrates. What i dont understand is why this question is downrated. Please explain why you downrate. In my world, this is i clean and simple question???

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I have plenty of ASP.NET knowledge. The fact is that your question and answer have nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: If this not is ASP.NET Code '<%=Request.Url.AbsoluteUri%>' then I possible is Santa Claus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) property will contain that information.

```
var url = location.href;
```

Comment: According to the documentation for [AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx), it returns a string containing the absolute URI. `location.href` is a string containing the absolute URI. So no, you don't need to parse it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Sorry for the missunderstanding. Many thanks!