# Get current URL address by javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get current URL like this.

For example, if the url is:

http://www.test.com/app/one.bc

I want to get the path without the address the main page so like:

/app/one.bc

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: so you want to know the `pathname` in the current `window` or `document`  `location`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504686/get-relative-path-of-the-page-url-using-javascript/34020609

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: A simple google search will be enough to find the answer

Comment: In the current `window`

Comment: helpful to you [JavaScript Window Location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score -2):

try using console.log(this.$route);